# Find() a specified amount of records in mongo/python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to get(find()) the first 1000 records in my mongodb collection using python.

```
for rooms in range(1000):
    rooms = list(db.rooms.find())
    print(rooms)
```

But this doesn't work; it prints all my records 100 times. Can anyone suggest a tweek that will allow me to get the first 1000 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a field by which the result set are ordered, I think that should work:

```
>>> rooms = list(db.rooms.find().limit(1000))
>>> print(rooms)
```

or

```
>>> rooms = list(db.rooms.find()[:1000])
>>> print(rooms)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was easy enough!! :-)